# Consequences of accepting a friend request

Tags: battle.net

What are the consequences of accepting a friend request on battle.net?

Recently I received a friend request from someone and I don't know who it is. I can't think of a way of asking them who they are and why they added me, without accepting the friend request first.

If I accept their friend request, what will change? Will I be able to put things back the way they were before I accepted the friend request?

Comment: Was this a BattleTag friend request, or a RealID friend request? Implications are slightly different depending which it was.

Comment: @JonK how might I tell the difference? I don't remember giving my  BattleTag to anyone recently, in fact I don't think I've given it to anyone other than those on my friends list. I presume that ReadID uses the account email address, if that is so, then I have given that email address to people and used it for various things over the years, but I can't think of anything I did with it recently, and I'm certain that I haven't given anyone cause to add me from in game activities.

Comment: BattleTag requests would just display some sort of character name for the sender, whereas a RealID request would show you their real name. That's the simplest way of telling them apart.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accepting a friend request will allow that player to see when you are online, see what game you are playing (and limited information about what you're doing in that game) and send you battlenet messages. This will also enable certain interactions in some games, such as challenging them in Hearthstone.

You can remove a friend at any time.

Comment: A little extra: "limited information" in this case is gamemode in Starcraft, zone in World of Warcraft, and probably also gamemode on Hearthstone